# Exercise on The Definition of Tangent Vector via Curve (Jeffrey Lee)

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Following Jeffrey Lee's book p.58 we have the following definition.

$\textbf{Definition} : $Let $c_1,c_2  : I\rightarrow M$ be a curves with $0 \in I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $c_1(0)=c_2(0)=p \in M$. We say that $c_1$ is tangent to $c_2$ at $p$ iff $\forall f \in C^{\infty}(U)$ where $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $p$, we have 
$$
(f \circ c_1)'(0) = (f \circ c_2)'(0)
$$
$\textbf{Exercise : }$I asked to show that $c_1$ tangent to $c_2$ at $p$ iff $\forall f \in C^{\infty}(M)$ we have 
$$
(f \circ c_1)'(0) = (f \circ c_2)'(0)
$$
The hint from the book is by using cut-off function argument.

There are few questions i wanna ask.

1) First is the definition is valid ? Because we know that the curves is mapped to $M$ and the function is only defined on some open neighbourhood $U$ of $p$. Although i think its fine because whenwe taking derivatives of $(f \circ c_1)$ we only care about the local behaviour, i still fell uneasy about the composition. Should we interpret the image of the curves is contained in $U$ ?

2) Second, i think i can show $\implies $ part by restrict the global function to $U$ : Let $f \in C^{\infty}(M)$, $f|_U := f \circ \iota$ where $\iota : U \hookrightarrow M $, because i assume that $c(I)\subset U$, then $\iota \circ c_i = c_i$. So
$$
(f|_U \circ c_1)'(0) = (f \circ \iota \circ c_1)'(0) = (f \circ c_1)'(0) 
$$
and doing the same for $c_2$. By hypothesis $(f|_U \circ c_1)'(0) = (f|_U \circ c_2)'(0)$. So
$$
 (f \circ c_1)'(0)  = (f \circ c_2)'(0)
$$
Is this correct ?

3). I dont know how to to show $\impliedby$ part. Please give me hint. I only know extend function on a closed subset. Since $U$ is open, i'm not sure how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: **HINT**: Take a bump function $\rho$ defined on $M$ that is $1$ on a neighborhood of $p$ and consider $\rho\cdot f$.

Comment: @TedShifrin : Thank you prof Ted. But i still work on the details about how to choose the nbhd.

Comment: Choose a bump function supported in $U$ that is $1$ on any neighborhood of $p$. Typically it's easiest to work with balls in some chart at $p$ to define $\rho$, but I assumed you knew about construction/existence of bump functions.